# Which FreeBSD port brings this accepted patch onto my system?

Tags: freebsd

I have FreeBSD 10.1.  I need the update discussed at https://reviews.freebsd.org/D932 to libexec/rtld-elf/rtld.c, so when c/c++ programs call dl_iterate_phdr, they get the response with the new code.

How do I figure out which ports directory would bring in this commit?  (To avoid a lengthy update for everything)

As a curiosity question, not a complaint, if FreeBSD 10.1 was released Nov 11-14 2014, and this commit was accepted on Oct 9 2014, why wasn't it in 10.1-release?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's for basesystem, not ports.  It was committed to 11-CURRENT in r272842, then merged to 10-STABLE in r274531, and will ship with the next FreeBSD release (10.2).

Comment: Thanks!  That page does mention "Committed in r272842".  From that, how did you figure out that commit was to 11-CURRENT?  And, how did you figure out there was another commit (r274531) that was to 10-STABLE?  (I'd love to learn what I'm missing likely about git, svn, or cvs, that would help me answer this myself.)

Comment: Commits to the basesystem pretty much always go to HEAD first - and HEAD is right now, until 11.0-RELEASE, called 11-CURRENT.  So, I've checked there first.

Stuff usually gets merged to stable tree after some time; I simply did "svn log" in 10-STABLE checkout and searched for "r272842" in the commit messages.